linear regression by coefficieents and intercept---
I want to plot a linear regression by its coefficients and intercept. I've seen its code on Jupiter notebook .but I couldn't understand a special part of that .this is the code :
plt.scatter(train.ENGINESIZE, train.CO2EMISSION, color='blue')
plt.plot ( train_x, regr.coef_[0][0]*train_x +regr.intercept_[0], '-r')

why it wouldn't be like regr.coef_*train_x +regr.intercept_

Please provide a [mre]. The important part of the code is missing here. The line you provide is correct. It plots ax+b vs x. What is missing is "how do you get a and b1". Apparently it is regr.coef_[0]0] where you would expect to be regr.coef_. But we know nothing of regr. You haven't show where that regr come from. Only by knowing this regr we could tell if it is supposed to ba a scalar or an array of array.
